# Are these good questions? - What does "Dungeon" mean in "Dungeons and Dragons", and how did that meaning come about?

Tags: discussion, questions

Are these good questions? - What does "Dungeon" mean in "Dungeons and Dragons", and how did that meaning come about?

I've also tried to scope stuff out around this on [the English.SE Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/are-either-of-these-dungeons-and-dragons-related-questions-good-questions) and [Scifi.SE meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7158/has-this-been-asked-before-how-did-dungeon-evolved-to-mean-place-where-adv).

Asked: [Why does “dungeon” mean the places adventurers go to kill stuff?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67422/why-do-dd-and-other-rpgs-players-use-dungeon-to-mean-the-places-they-go-to)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - Asked: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67422/why-do-dd-and-other-rpgs-players-use-dungeon-to-mean-the-places-they-go-to

Comment: answered as best I could.

Answer (score 5):

It's the title of a possibly **topical** question, but it literally lacks body. Without seeing it in its full question form, we can't guarantee whether the community will think it's *good*.

It's certainly on-topic, within our [terminology](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and [history-of-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-gaming) tags, but beyond that mere topicality, judgement about quality would have to be determined the usual way, by people voting on it as a real question on the main site.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of? As SSD says, you're missing the body of the question completely so it's hard to judge, but it's on topic for us. I'm also confused about what exactly you're asking for. *You* might be confused about what you're asking for, since the Dungeon part of the title literally just refers to a Dungeon (it's meant to be evocative), but your other meta questions suggest you're curious about how the language is actually used nowadays and what's with the way people use it and why it came to be that way.

You might want to just ask that straightforwardly: "what's with D&D players using 'dungeon' the way they do to mean all kinds of places they go kill stuff?" or something.

Comment: Okay, I'll try your title suggestion... But what could I put for the body? "What's with D&D players using 'dungeon' the way they do to mean all kinds of places they go kill stuff?", makes it pretty clear what I'm asking...

Comment: @Malandy Tell us a bit about what you know on the matter. Tell us if there's anything in particular you want to know about it. It will show us whether there's any gaps in your knowledge we should fill and whether any are worthy of special attention.

Comment: Asked: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67422/why-do-dd-and-other-rpgs-players-use-dungeon-to-mean-the-places-they-go-to